# JS - detect Connection Reset

Tags: reactjs, fetch, connection-reset

In our React application, we have the ability to upload files.
Our FW is configured to virusscan the incoming files (posted via multipart form).

When a virus is detected the connection is reset ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Is there a way to "catch" a connection reset in JS and give an appropriate message to the user?
I don't like pôlling solutions ;-)

Comment: bump. I want to know. Vanilla js anwers welcome, I dont use react.